# Electron App Error: EACCES: permission denied, open

Tags: npm, gulp, console, electron, tray

```
[20:25:45] Using gulpfile ~/Desktop/GitHub/electra/gulpfile.js
[20:25:45] Starting 'build-client-bundles'...
[20:25:45] Starting 'build-client-scss'...
[20:25:45] Starting 'build-client-html'...
[20:25:45] Starting 'build-client-assets'...
[20:25:45] Starting 'build-server'...
[20:25:45] Starting 'watch-client'...
[20:25:45] Finished 'watch-client' after 16 ms
[20:25:45] Starting 'watch-server'...
[20:25:45] Finished 'watch-server' after 1.58 ms
[20:25:45] Starting 'watch'...
[20:25:45] Finished 'watch' after 13 μs
./app/assets/assignment.png
stream.js:74
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
      ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/ugrerdl/Desktop/GitHub/electra/build/index.js'
    at Error (native)
```

I got this error when I try to run my app. Btw: if I try with sudo every think work.

Comment: Are you sure the permissions are correctly set? Sudo only starts the node process with sudo but not your application. Make sure your folders and files are readable because that's what EACCES actually means.

Comment: Make sure you use true `dependency` or `devDependency` on package.json

Comment: @EmreYILMAZ Yeap thats my fault  I've confused I added on package json on `devDependency` instead of `dependency`. Thank you for your answer